# Can you use `include?` in greater than statements?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find out if a string includes more than two occurrences of a certain symbol. For example,

```
is_valid_email("joey@g@mail.com")
```

should return `false` if there are more than two `"@"` or `"."`. Can I use something like this?

```
if string.include?("@") > 2
  return false
else
  return true
end
```

Comment: What does `String#include?` return? If it's not a number, then no, you can't do this. There are other methods, though.

Comment: As already pointed out, you can use `count` for your immediate issue. But really, you need something more robust for email validation. It's not so simple. You'll have to use regex.

Comment: I understand, this is just for an example I am working through, and wanted to see if there was a way to check against same types of characters in a string.

Comment: BTW, your example address `joey@g@mail.com` doesn't contain _more_ than 2 `@` symbols, it contains _exactly_ 2. You probably want `>= 2`. And regarding the `.` – it's perfectly fine for email addresses to have several dots, e.g. `joey.doe@mail.example.com`

Comment: For testing email addresses you probably want a loose RFC822-style validator.

Comment: Consider adding a question mark to the method name (`is_email_address?` ). Better, perhaps: `valid_email_address?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count). Also, there's not much point in an `if` statement that just returns `true` or `false`; the boolean condition itself is already `true` or `false`, so you can simply return it directly. In this case, since the `if` part returns `false` and the `else` returns `true`, you can negate the condition:

```
return !(string.count('@') >= 2)
```

Or use the opposite condition:

```
return string.count('@') < 2
```

But if you're validating that a string looks like an email address, it seems like you would want to make sure it contains exactly one "@":

```
return string.count('@') == 1
```

You can leave the `return` keyword off as long as there's no additional code after this check in the method body; a method automatically returns the value of its last expression.